# Lua not recognized as an internal or external command, What did I do wrong?

Tags: lua

I installed Lua using "winget install "lua for windows"" It says it installed but when I type lua and also lua53, or lua54 at command prompt it tells me "lua is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

[image: Command Prompt]

I installed the file using the installer, and expected the lua version to be displayed when I entered lua at the command prompt.

Comment: Just open another command prompt and try.

Answer (score 1):

run from cmd:

```
echo %path%
```

and see, the output should contain a path like this:

```
C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1;C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\clibs;C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\include;
```

add if needed:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1;C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\clibs;C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\include
```

Answer (score -2):

Lua has to be capitalized to run!

Comment: Windows is not case sensitive, and Lua is installed using lower case.